# Php date() Date and time is stuck

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am using a cut paste code which explodes the time and date stamp to save it in mysql in this format DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS PM. 
When it executes the date is stuck to 16/01/13 and time to 11:59. 
I dont know much php so dont know whats wrong.

Here is the code

```
    $datm9=date("d/m/y h:i:s A");
                //explode the date
                    $datm_pass=explode(" ",$datm9);
                    $datm_pass_set = $datm_pass[1].$datm_pass[2];
                    $hours_test = explode(":",$datm_pass[1]);
                    $hours_t = $hours_test[0];
                    $hoursext_t =$datm_pass[2];
            //if only for the date 

                if(($hours_t=='12' && $hoursext_t=='AM')or ($hours_t=='01' && $hoursext_t=='AM') or ($hours_t=='02' && $hoursext_t=='AM') or ($hours_t=='03' && $hoursext_t=='AM')){

                    $datm_pass_set_d = explode("/",$datm_pass[0]);
                    $fd=($datm_pass_set_d[0]-1);
                    $dat_fix = $fd."/".$datm_pass_set_d[1]."/".$datm_pass_set_d[2];

                    //09/11/11 11:59:49 AM
                    $datm = $dat_fix." "."11:59:49 AM";
                    //$datm=date("d/m/y h:i:s A");  
                    $today=$dat_fix;        
            }else{

            $datm=date("d/m/y h:i:s A");
            $today=date('d/m/y');
        }
```

Comment: You're not texting here, get used to typing the whole word in business communications.

Comment: don't treat dates as a string to manipulate them, this never works well.

Answer (score 5):

mysql's standard/native date format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. If you feed in anything else, mysql will interpret it as best it can, but will fail (as it is in your case). Don't try to use another format. And what's with all the explode stuff? If you want to manipulate the date variable, then don't use all those round-trips from time->string->whatever->string->whatever->etc...

Comment: (Aside: "*Don't try to use another format*" - MySQL does of course recognise [some other datetime literal formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html)).

Comment: will try with standard format as this format is going over my head...thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out

```
strtotime
```

You will enjoy that function.

something like this might suit you

```
//convert date
function convertDate($date, $into = 'F jS, Y') {
    $asdate = strtotime($date);
    $asdate = date($into, $asdate);
    return $asdate;
}
```

No need to get all crazy with dates...

Answer (score 0):

Now you know the mysql string Format for TimeStamp/DateTime/Date/Time etc.
You can create any format for php script in easy process to use php Date Time Class
see: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php